# How do I get my Django + React Application running in production mode on apache2 with Pipenv?

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, python, python3, django

I am doing a group project with Django and React and each of us has been given its own VM to run it on. At the moment we are only able to start a development server for Django with the "runserver" command and a server to compile our react code with "npm start". The backend is then accessible on port 8000 and the frontend on port 3000.
We are now trying to get this configuration running so that it is continually accessible and we can configure HTTPS.
We have tried many different internet tutorials (and probably broke some things underway) but we can't seem to get it running. Last one we tried was https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
The server is still not accessible at its IP.
Our VM is a Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie), we are using Pipenv version 2018.10.13 as out virtual environment with Python 3.4.2 and Django 2.0.10. Our apache is ver. 0.91-ubuntu1.

Here is my apache2.conf:

```
# This is the main Apache server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ for detailed information about
# the directives and /usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian about Debian specific
# hints.
#
#
# Summary of how the Apache 2 configuration works in Debian:
# The Apache 2 web server configuration in Debian is quite different to
# upstream's suggested way to configure the web server. This is because Debian's
# default Apache2 installation attempts to make adding and removing modules,
# virtual hosts, and extra configuration directives as flexible as possible, in
# order to make automating the changes and administering the server as easy as
# possible.

# It is split into several files forming the configuration hierarchy outlined
# below, all located in the /etc/apache2/ directory:
#
#       /etc/apache2/
#       |-- apache2.conf
#       |       `--  ports.conf
#       |-- mods-enabled
#       |       |-- *.load
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       |-- conf-enabled
#       |       `-- *.conf
#       `-- sites-enabled
#               `-- *.conf
#
#
# * apache2.conf is the main configuration file (this file). It puts the pieces
#   together by including all remaining configuration files when starting up the
#   web server.
#
# * ports.conf is always included from the main configuration file. It is
#   supposed to determine listening ports for incoming connections which can be
#   customized anytime.
#
# * Configuration files in the mods-enabled/, conf-enabled/ and sites-enabled/
#   directories contain particular configuration snippets which manage modules,
#   global configuration fragments, or virtual host configurations,
#   respectively.
#
#   They are activated by symlinking available configuration files from their
#   respective *-available/ counterparts. These should be managed by using our
#   helpers a2enmod/a2dismod, a2ensite/a2dissite and a2enconf/a2disconf. See
#   their respective man pages for detailed information.
#
# * The binary is called apache2. Due to the use of environment variables, in
#   the default configuration, apache2 needs to be started/stopped with
#   /etc/init.d/apache2 or apache2ctl. Calling /usr/bin/apache2 directly will not
#   work with the default configuration.


# Global configuration
#

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# NOTE!  If you intend to place this on an NFS (or otherwise network)
# mounted filesystem then please read the Mutex documentation (available
# at <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#mutex>);
# you will save yourself a lot of trouble.
#
# Do NOT add a slash at the end of the directory path.
#
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
# The accept serialization lock file MUST BE STORED ON A LOCAL DISK.
#
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

#
# PidFile: The file in which the server should record its process
# identification number when it starts.
# This needs to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
#
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 300
#
# KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
# one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
#
KeepAlive On

#
# MaxKeepAliveRequests: The maximum number of requests to allow
# during a persistent connection. Set to 0 to allow an unlimited amount.
# We recommend you leave this number high, for maximum performance.
#
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

#
# KeepAliveTimeout: Number of seconds to wait for the next request from the
# same client on the same connection.
#
KeepAliveTimeout 5


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

#
# HostnameLookups: Log the names of clients or just their IP addresses
# e.g., www.apache.org (on) or 204.62.129.132 (off).
# The default is off because it'd be overall better for the net if people
# had to knowingly turn this feature on, since enabling it means that
# each client request will result in AT LEAST one lookup request to the
# nameserver.
#
HostnameLookups Off

# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

#
# LogLevel: Control the severity of messages logged to the error_log.
# Available values: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the log level for particular modules, e.g.
# "LogLevel info ssl:warn"
#
LogLevel warn

# Include module configuration:
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

# Include list of ports to listen on
Include ports.conf
# Sets the default security model of the Apache2 HTTPD server. It does
# not allow access to the root filesystem outside of /usr/share and /var/www.
# The former is used by web applications packaged in Debian,
# the latter may be used for local directories served by the web server. If
# your system is serving content from a sub-directory in /srv you must allow
# access here, or in any related virtual host.
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>




# AccessFileName: The name of the file to look for in each directory
# for additional configuration directives.  See also the AllowOverride
# directive.
#
AccessFileName .htaccess

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>


#
# The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
# a CustomLog directive.
#
# These deviate from the Common Log Format definitions in that they use %O
# (the actual bytes sent including headers) instead of %b (the size of the
# requested file), because the latter makes it impossible to detect partial
# requests.
#
# Note that the use of %{X-Forwarded-For}i instead of %h is not recommended.
# Use mod_remoteip instead.
#
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

# TODO
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so
# This is just the root of your virtualenv directory, i.e. two levels above activate
WSGIPythonHome /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-nwAt4pcf/bin/
WSGIPythonPath /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-nwAt4pcf/bin/python3.4


<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And my backend.conf:

```
Listen 8000
<VirtualHost *:8000>
  ServerName webspec68.mi
  ServerAdmin xxx@xxx-xxx.xx
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/puppy-webshop/backend

  # Point this to the wsgi.py in the same directory as your settings.py file
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/puppy-webshop/backend/backend/wsgi.py

  <Directory /var/www/html/puppy-webshop/backend>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
      Allow from all
    </Files>
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And finally the frontend.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName webspec68.mi
  ServerAdmin xxx@xxx-xxx.xx
  DocumentRoot /var/www/frontend

  # Serve static files like the minified javascript from npm run-script build
  Alias /static /var/www/todo/frontend/build/static
  <Directory /var/www/todo/frontend/build/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The error.log is constantly logging these errors:

```
"ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
[Sun Jan 20 17:59:59.887686 2019] [core:notice] [pid 20413:tid 140450917902208] AH00052: child pid 20430 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Sun Jan 20 18:00:00.889711 2019] [wsgi:warn] [pid 20431:tid 140450917902208] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=20431): Unable to stat Python home /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-nwAt4pcf/bin/. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
```

**The project is currently under /var/www/html/my-project/. Should our backend part be in /var/www/backend and our frontend in /var/www/frontend?
Also the WSGIPythonHome and WSGIPythonPath are just a guess as I can't find a tutorial for doing this with pipenv. These seem like the main problems for now.
There is probably a lot wrong here but I am pretty new to all of this. Appreciate any help!**

Comment: The answer is in the question "ImportError: No module named 'encodings'. Something is wrong with your python setup.

Comment: Python should be installed in my virtual environment (pipenv). I just don‘t know which path exactly I should use then for Home and for Path. Also, the code is supposed to be in /var/www/backend and /var/www/frontend, right? Because as of now it is in /var/www/html/my-project/backend and frontend